# Like button using Ajax not working in Django project

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-templates

I am stuck on a problem I am having trying to implement a 'Like' button into my django application.

I have the functionality working for the models, and even in the html template the code works if I manually add a like from a user.

It seems like my Ajax may be the issue, but I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is my models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    direct_url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    post_url = models.URLField()
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    time_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Like(models.Model):
    liker = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='likes')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Like, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And here is my views.py

```
class PostListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'homepage/home.html'
    ordering = ['-time_posted']
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = datetime.now()
        context['likesbyuser'] = Like.objects.filter(liker=self.request.user)
        return context


def likePost(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post_id = request.GET['post_id']
        likedpost = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)  # getting the liked post

        if Like.objects.filter(post=likedpost, liker=request.user).exists():
            Like.objects.filter(post=likedpost, liker=request.user).delete()
        else:
            m = Like(post=likedpost, liker=request.user)  # creating like object
            m.save()  # saves into database
        return HttpResponse(likedpost.likes.count())
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Request method is not a GET")
```

This is part of the template, where I am putting the buttons to use the Ajax which should call the like function:

```
{% for i in post.likes.all %}
                    {% if user == i.liker %}
                            <a class='likebutton' data-catid="{{ post.id }}"><i id='like{{ post.id }}' class="btn fas fa-heart fa-lg post-buttons "></i></a>
                    {% elif forloop.last %}
                            <a class='likebutton' data-catid="{{ post.id }}"><i id='like{{ post.id }}' class="btn far fa-heart fa-lg post-buttons "></i></a>
                    {% endif %}

            {% empty %}
                    <a class='likebutton' data-catid="{{ post.id }}"><i id='like{{ post.id }}' class="btn far fa-heart fa-lg post-buttons "></i></a>

            {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And here is the Ajax code I am adding to the base.html in script tags.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('main').on('click', '.likebutton', function(){
    var catid;
    catid = $(this).attr("data-catid");
$.ajax(
{
    type:"GET",
    url: "/likepost/",
    data:{
        post_id: catid
    },
    success: function(data){

    if(data==0){
        $('.like' + catid).toggle();
        $('#like' + catid).toggleClass("far fas");
        $('#likecount' + catid).html('');
        console.log(data+'if');
    }

    else if(data==1){
        if($('.like' + catid).is(":hidden"))
        {
            $('.like' + catid).toggle();
        }

        $('#like' + catid).toggleClass("far fas");
        $('#likecount' + catid).html(data + ' like');
        console.log(data+'elseif');
    }
    else{

        $('#like' + catid).toggleClass("far fas");
        $('#likecount' + catid).html(data + ' likes');
        console.log(data+'else');
        }
    }

})
});
</script>
```

I have tried adding event.preventDefault(); to the ajax call, but that did not fix my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.

I was pointing the Ajax code at "main" as seen in the following snippet:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
$('main').on('click', '.likebutton', function(){
...
```

My issue was that I forgot to surround the block with the main tag when I ported this project over.

In my base.html I added the following code:

```
<main role="main" class="container h-100">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}
</main>
```

This fixed the issue.